# Google Cloud Storage permission issue

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I am getting an error performing any Google Cloud Storage action from Cloud Functions. I keep getting the error `[project-id]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get`. I have given the service admin different roles including `editor`, `storage admin` and `storage object admin` but non seem to work.

Below is the test function.

```
exports.test = async (req, res) => {

  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  // Gets the ACL for the bucket
  const [acls] = await storage.bucket('sharedbox').acl.get();

  acls.forEach(acl => {
    console.log(`${acl.role}: ${acl.entity}`);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code slightly and created a Node.js 8 HTTP triggered Google Cloud Function that was executed correctly and retrieved the ACL for the bucket. Follow the steps bellow and it should work for you too:

1. Create a new Google Cloud Function with name of your choice.
2. Trigger `HTTP`.
3. Runtime `Node.js 8`.
4. In `package.json` replace everything with:

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
     "@google-cloud/storage" : "^2.4.3" 
  }
}
```

5. Under **Function to execute** add `getAClGoogleCloudStorage`.
6. Inside the `index.js` replace all the code with [this code from GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Cloud%20Functions/get_gcs_bucket_acls_node.js).
7. Click on `CREATE`.

After successful creation, go to the Cloud Function's details page and click on `Trigger` tab. Click the URL provided for the trigger and you should see `Execution finished!` as response.

When checking The Cloud Function's logs, you will notice the OWNER... ,READER ... ACLs of the bucket listed.

I have tested the code above and it works without giving me any access permission issues.